# Iterar una lista y guardarla en un archivo

Tags: python, lista, archivo, python-2.x, bucle-for

Estoy intentando iterar una lista y luego guardarla en un archivo `.txt` con `open/write`.

```
lista = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres']
mi_path = "../fichero.txt"
f = open(mi_path, 'a+')

for i in lista:
    f.write(i)
    f.close()
```

Le doy el atributo `a+` para que re-escriba el archivo `.txt` y siga desde la ultima posición, el problema es que solo me guarda el primer elemento de la lista. Al hacer el bucle `for` lo que quiero es que registre los 3 campos de la lista que le estoy dando, pero solo lo hace con el primero.

Comment: Puedes probar a crear un string con todos los elementos de la lista, con el bucle for, y luego añadir dicho string al fichero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solo te guarda el primer elemento de la lista porque en la primera iteración del bucle, después de escribir el primer elemento, cierras el archivo.

Para solucionarlo tienes que cerrar el archivo una vez hayas acabado de grabar elementos en él. Intenta lo siguiente:

```
lista = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres']
mi_path = "../fichero.txt"
f = open(mi_path, 'a+')

for i in lista:
    f.write(i)

f.close()
```

También puedes hacerlo un poco más sencillo usando la definición `with`:

```
lista = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres']
mi_path = "../fichero.txt"

with open(mi_path, 'a+') as f:
    for i in lista:
        f.write(i)
```

De esta manera, todo lo que está dentro del `with` se ejecuta para el archivo abierto. Y una vez termine la ejecución dentro del `with` cierra automáticamente el archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! correcto, tengo que cerrar el archivo después del bucle.

Comment: @DevpDevp recuerda marcar una respuesta como aceptada. Ambos ganais rep ;)

Answer (score 5):

Tienes que cerrar el archivo después del bucle:

```
lista = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres']
f = open("fichero.txt", "a")

for i in lista:
    f.write(i)

f.close()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era precisamente eso.